# Movesense with Unity BLE plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth-lowenergy, movesense

I am trying to get the Movesense to work with a Unity BLE asset as originally I thought MS would be simple enough. I have managed to connect to it and subscribed to the "61353090-" starting service and the "34802252-" starting charasteristic. I think I even got some notifications. Now the problem is, that I am not receiving or able to decode any data from there.

I also ended up reading the example codes and found out the complex system the Movesense uses and the "whiteboard", which I am unfamiliar with. I cannot find anything sensible by googling, as whiteboard is a whiteboard :)

Now my questions are:

- What should I do to progress? Do I need to write something to the "17816557"?
- What is the "whiteboard" actually?
- Would it actually be smarter to just make a Unity plugin for the Movesense?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect anyone who can grok any of this will need a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are quite right that the answer is in the "Whiteboard" component. Whiteboard is the embedded REST framework (Note: it is not over HTTP!) that Movesense uses to implement REST services within as well as inter device (e.g. over UART or BLE). As you can imagine it is not a simple component, so decoding the traffic without Amersports'/Suunto's help is quite a big challenge. The actual BLE layer is simple: one characteristic to each direction (write & notify), the complexity lies in what goes inside that data pipe.

However, if you are trying to use Unity to make a mobile app the situation is not so bad. There has been a prototype of Movesense mobile library integration for Unity (Android) that uses the existing Movesense mobile library. If you ask Movesense team (*info (at) movesense.com*) they might be able to help you further. For Windows (Unity or plain) there is nothing done (at least not yet) mainly because until Windows 10 there was no official BLE API for Windows.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Sorry for the spam, I am unfamiliar with SOF and used too long time for the edit.

Thank you for the clarification. Out of interest, is there any documentation about Whiteboard? Is it designed by Suunto or by 3rd party?

The prototype sounds good and seems the only way to go for now. Even though I have been aiming for iOS for now. Anyway I am targeting both for them in the end. Any plans for iOS library?

I have actually been in contact with Suunto already, but for the time being I was recommended to use SOF. I will anyway also contact the address you gave.

Thank you very much

Comment: Marking as the accepted answer, as I believe this is the best possible answer for such a complex matter.